# grapesjs how to disable embedAsBase64?

Tags: javascript, html, image, grapesjs

I try to disable grapesjs embedAsBase64 on the image insert without success!

From this :

```
<img id="irik" data-gjs-type="image" draggable="true"
src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNCAyNCIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IHJnYmEoMCwwLDAsMC4xNSk7IHRyYW5zZm9ybTogc2NhbGUoMC43NSkiPgogICAgICAgIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik04LjUgMTMuNWwyLjUgMyAzLjUtNC41IDQuNSA2SDVtMTYgMVY1YTIgMiAwIDAgMC0yLTJINWMtMS4xIDAtMiAuOS0yIDJ2MTRjMCAxLjEuOSAyIDIgMmgxNGMxLjEgMCAyLS45IDItMnoiPjwvcGF0aD4KICAgICAgPC9zdmc+" class="gjs-plh-image">
```

To this :

```
<img id="irik" data-gjs-type="image" draggable="true" 
  src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11614725?s=52&v=4"
  class="gjs-plh-image">
```

this its my code but still not works!! please help!

```
var editor  = grapesjs.init({
    height: '100%',
    container : '#gjs',
    fromElement: true,
    showOffsets: true,
    embedAsBase64: false,
    assetManager: {
         storageType   : '',
         embedAsBase64: false,
        // assets: images
        custom: true,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
assetManager: {
storageType     : '',
   storeOnChange  : true,
   storeAfterUpload  : true,
   upload: 'images',  
   assets       : [ ],
    uploadFile: function(e) {
   var files = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files : e.target.files;
var formData = new FormData();
   for(var i in files){
           formData.append('file-'+i, files[i]) //containing all the selected images from local
   }
   
$.ajax({
url: 'upload_image.php',
type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       contentType:false,
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'json',
mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
processData:false,
success: function(result){
               var myJSON = [];
               $.each( result['data'], function( key, value ) {
                       myJSON[key] = value;    
               });
               var images = myJSON;    
         editor.AssetManager.add(images); 
           }
});
},
},

upload_image.php:


if($_FILES)
{
$resultArray = array();
foreach ( $_FILES as $file){
            $fileName = $file['name'];
            $tmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $file['size'];
            $fileType = $file['type'];
            if ($file['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
            {
                    error_log($file['error']);
                    echo JSON_encode(null);
            }           
$uploadDir = "../images/";
$targetPath = $uploadDir. $fileName;
move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $targetPath);
$finalDir = "../images/";
$finalPath = $finalDir. $fileName;
            $result=array(
                    'name'=>$fileName,
                    'type'=>'image',
                    'src'=>$finalPath,
                    'height'=>350,
                    'width'=>250
            );
            array_push($resultArray, $result);
}    
$response = array( 'data' => $resultArray );
echo json_encode($response);
}
```